# Closing Side Drawer shifts the UI up in main layout

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

I am having this UI in main layout and I am having side drawer but what happens is when I open and then close side drawer then the UI shifts up and hide the view pager and then I have to manually scroll up to see view pager..This happens after I close side drawer. Please guide me to solve this problem..

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myfont="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.itw.b2b.vastradeal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"
    tools:context="com.itw.b2b.vastradeal.fragment.HomeFragment"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollviewHome"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
      >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/White">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/titles"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/middle_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lable_Category_Layout">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/custom_grid_home"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/White"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:columnWidth="160dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
```